# input validation with float as the correct type

Tags: c, scanf

I have to accept an input in the rang -5 to 5. The input is suppose to be of type float. I have tried the different methods suggested on this site but they do not work.

my code

```
     while(1)
     {
            while(1)
            {
                    printf("Please enter input voltage (-5V to 5V): ");
                    if((scanf("%f",&e) == 1){
                         if(e < -5.0 || e > 5.0) /*checks to make sure input is correct*/
                         {
                                 printf("Please enter another input voltage.");
                                 continue;
                         }
                         break;
                     else
                     {
                           printf("please enter new input.");
                           continue;
                     }
            }

            d = (e+5)*(4095)/(10); /*manual calculation for digital encoding*/

            printf("The conversion in decimal is: %d\n",d);
            printf("The conversion in hex is: %X\n\n",d);

            printf("Would you like to continue (y/n)? ");/*prompt to end program*/
            scanf("%c",&userInput);
            if(userInput == 'y') {continue;}
            if(userInput == 'n') {break;}

      }
```

This still causes and infinite loop if say my input is "y".
Since other methods did not work for me am I doing them wrong or is this a special case?

EDIT:
To those asking the whole program is a controlled while(1) loop because at the end another user input is taken to see if the program should end or repeat. Sorry for not mentioning this.

Comment: See http://www.sscce.org

Comment: What *is* your input, and how can there be an infinite loop when you've only posted an if/else? (Obviously there's more code; what I'm getting at is that you need to show it if it's part of the problem.)

Comment: @dvnrrs The whole program is in a while(1) because at the end I check if user wants to repeat or not.

Comment: @user3341518: show us the program that doesn't work instead of letting us guess.

Comment: @user3341518: This is pseudo code. Show us your real code that doesn't work.

Comment: @user3341518: your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Just put in a space before `"%c"` to consme the leftover `\n` from `scanf("%f",&e)`.  `scanf(" %c",&userInput);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
void main()
{
  float e ;
  char userInput ;

  while(1)
  {
    while(1)
    {
      printf("Please enter input voltage (-5V to 5V): ");

      if (scanf("%f",&e) == 1)
      {
        if(e < -5.0 || e > 5.0) /*checks to make sure input is correct*/
        {
          printf("Please enter another input voltage.\n");
          continue;
        }
        else
          break ;
      }
    }

    float d = (e+5)*(4095)/(10); /*manual calculation for digital encoding*/

    printf("The conversion in decimal is: %d\n",d);
    printf("The conversion in hex is: %X\n\n",d);

    printf("Would you like to continue (y/n)? ");/*prompt to end program*/

    scanf("\n%c", &userInput);
    if(userInput == 'y') {continue;}
    if(userInput == 'n') {break;}
  }
}
```

It's not very elegant, I just modified your solution so it exits the loop as soon as you have entered a value between -5 and +5.

Comment: Even with your code if my input is anything but a number it gets thrown into an infinite loop. With "please enter input voltage (-5V to 5V)" repeated.

Comment: `scanf` is weird, use `fgets` instead and convert the string to float with `strtod`.